# "DomContentLoaded" isn't working in my browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, addeventlistener

I wrote my html page like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="Natural1.jpg" id="img1" >
 <audio src="sound.mp3" id="audio1" ></audio>
</div>
```

And my javascript file is this:

```
function init(){
    audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    img1.addEventListener("click", imgClick, false);
}
function imgClick(){
    if(audio1.paused){
        audio1.play();
    }
    else{
        audio1.pause();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DomContentLoaded', init, false);
```

I run that in chrome12, the script first execute the `document.addEventListener` method, but it did not go into the init method, why?
I tried `attachEvent` method instead `addEventListener` in IE8, but it still doesn't.
 what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might be the casing of th event name. Try the following instead:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Pretty sure this is the case. I tested the following:

```
document.addEventListener("DomContentLoaded", function(){ alert('Dom') }, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ alert('DOM') }, false);
```

On jsbin, and the latter event was raised alone. Note, IE8 will not raise this alert since this event doesn't take place there. Instead, you will find success from [IE9 and IE10](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/).

Example: http://jsbin.com/ocidok/edit#javascript,html

Browser support for `DOMContentLoaded` is cataloged on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded). As of today, this event is only available in the following browsers:

[image]

Comment: Should be noted that `DOMContentLoaded` won't work for him in the IE version he tried it `IE 8` because it got into IE only in the 9 version. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: @gdoron He tagged the question "google-chrome", so I assumed that was the browser he used. My bad.

Comment: You're right and I upvoted you, but when he will test your code in IE like he allready did it won't work for him and complain... :) `I tried attachEvent method instead addEventListener in **IE8**, but it steal not work. what's wrong with my code?`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript event names are **case-sensitive** strings. Therefore, capital and lowercase letters are **NOT** interchangeable in event names. So, changing the name from `'DomContentLoaded'` to `'DOMContentLoaded'` will fix the issue -- in Chrome at least.

As for IE 8: There's no way. The first version of IE to ever implement the `DOMContentLoaded` among other HTML5 events was version 9, so all I can say is: **Update your browser**! I also noticed that you're using the **16-version-out-of-date** Chrome 12, am I right? Seriously, **both browsers** need to be updated. Outdated browsers **pose serious security risks**. Good thing I as a Chromebook user am able to keep the most critical component to computer security -- the browser -- up-to-date VERY easily due to its seamless nature...